# How to test the following SQL script in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Below is a script written in Oracle 11g:

```
 MERGE INTO tblbio t
      USING (SELECT e.id, tblduplicate.cpid, e.bdt,e.LN, e.FN               
          FROM tblduplicate, entities where
          trim(e.id) = trim(tblduplicate.id)) source
      ON (t.cpid = source.cpid and trim(t.bdt) = trim(source.bdt))
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
UPDATE SET t.id = source.id, t.stat = '4'
WHERE  t.cmp = 'HHCC'
  AND t.thn = '2013'
  AND trim(lower(source.LN)) = trim(lower(t.LN))
  AND trim(lower(source.FN)) = trim(lower(t.FN))
  AND nvl(trim(t.bdt), ' ') <> ' '
  AND t.bdt <> '00000000'
  AND nvl(trim(source.bdt), ' ') <> ' '
  and source.bdt <> '00000000'
  AND t.stat <> '4'
```

Due to my data integrity problem, this script once in awhile will generate more than 1 records. In which this script will generate error.
I want to create validation prior this script is run. When my validation generate more than 1 records I stop this script from running. How can I do that?

I tried to write the following for my validation to capture record count but Oracle just did not like it.

```
 select* from tblbio t <-----
      USING (SELECT e.id, tblduplicate.cpid, e.bdt,e.LN, e.FN               
          FROM tblduplicate, entities where
          trim(e.id) = trim(tblduplicate.id)) source
      ON (t.cpid = source.cpid and trim(t.bdt) = trim(source.bdt))
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
select * from tblbio t <-----
WHERE  t.cmp = 'HHCC'
  AND t.thn = '2013'
  AND trim(lower(source.LN)) = trim(lower(t.LN))
  AND trim(lower(source.FN)) = trim(lower(t.FN))
  AND nvl(trim(t.bdt), ' ') <> ' '
  AND t.bdt <> '00000000'
  AND nvl(trim(source.bdt), ' ') <> ' '
  and source.bdt <> '00000000'
  AND t.stat <> '4'
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong.  Are you planning on running this in sql*plus or a pl/sql package, or some other client?

Comment: Why not let the script run, let an error be raised and then catch the error?

Comment: The script run just fine. I'm running the script from sql developer. The reason I want to validate this script in advance is to manually fix the record if the script generate more than 1 records. This script is a small part of a long procedure

Answer (score 0):

Converting original `MERGE` query to select from `tbiblio`:

- `MERGE INTO ... USING` --> `select from ... join`
- `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ... WHERE` --> `WHERE`

Final query:

```
select * from tblbio t 
      JOIN (SELECT e.id, tblduplicate.cpid, e.bdt,e.LN, e.FN               
          FROM tblduplicate, entities where
          trim(e.id) = trim(tblduplicate.id)) source
      ON (t.cpid = source.cpid and trim(t.bdt) = trim(source.bdt))
WHERE  t.cmp = 'HHCC'
  AND t.thn = '2013'
  AND trim(lower(source.LN)) = trim(lower(t.LN))
  AND trim(lower(source.FN)) = trim(lower(t.FN))
  AND nvl(trim(t.bdt), ' ') <> ' '
  AND t.bdt <> '00000000'
  AND nvl(trim(source.bdt), ' ') <> ' '
  and source.bdt <> '00000000'
  AND t.stat <> '4'
```